# reading output into variables inside the os.system command

Tags: linux, awk, python, readline

I have a `python` script which runs in Linux. I need to capture a command's output and store into variables and then should print the output. Code below -

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, time
systime=os.popen('date +"%m-%d-%y-%T"').read()
os.system("read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 < <(sar -u 1 1 | awk 'NR==4, NR==4 {print $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}')")
os.system("echo $systime,$c1,$c2,$c3,$c4,$c5,$c6 >> outputfile.txt")
```

I'm collecting the output given by the command `sar -u 1 1 | awk 'NR==4, NR==4 {print $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}')` into 6 variables - `c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 c6` using the read command. When i try to execute the above code, I get the below error -

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

I  even tried using `os.popen` instead of `os.system` but still end up getting the same error. Suggest me on how to store the variables using `os.system` command how to use them in the later stages. My target here is to print all the variables including the time being captured into a output file `outputfile.txt`. TIA

Comment: process substitution is a bash feature, so you'll need to tell python to use bash.

Answer (score 2):

`<(...)` is ksh syntax also recognised by `zsh` and `bash`, though when used as the target of a redirection, it's only supported by `zsh` and `bash`.

In any case, that is not `sh` syntax. Python's `os.system()` and `os.popen()` do run `sh` to interpret the given command line. And each invocation of those commands runs a new shell, so one variable defined in one will not be available in a the next shell invocation. Also `python` variables do not automagically become shell variables.

Here, you could do:

```
os.system("""
  sar -u 1 1 |
    awk -v t="$(date +%m-%d-%y-%T)" -v OFS=, '
      NR==4 {
        print t, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9
      }' > outputfile.txt""")
```

Though it feels silly to invoke `date` and `awk` (or even a shell) from within `python` while `python` is very well capable of doing their jobs itsef.